# How can I take the data from choiceSet in adaptive cards

Tags: javascript, json, botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I want the data (i.e value inside choices array) inside the red choiseSet when selected and clicked on the btn, I kept an image and added action submit as action.submit as that's my usecase, I am pretty much confused how I can do that, Here's the card payload

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.2",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
        "id": "myColor2",
        "style": "expanded",
        "value": "1",
        "choices": [
            {
                "title": "Red",
                "value": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Image",
        "altText": "it's a image",
        "url": "https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/bhutanese-ngultrum-btn-vector-id1304476894",
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
        "selectAction": {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "id": "btn",
            "title": "btn"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Once submitted by clicking on the icon, the bot should receive an activity of type `message` but with no text. The data you want is in the `value` property.

```json
{
  "activity": {
    "channelData": {
      "postBack": true,
      "clientActivityID": "<REMOVED>",
      "clientTimestamp": "2022-04-05T18:43:17.348Z"
    },
    "type": "message",
    "value": {
      "myColor2": "1"
    },
    "channelId": "emulator",
    "from": {
      "id": "<REMOVED>",
      "name": "",
      "role": "user"
    },
    "locale": "en-us",
    "localTimestamp": "2022-04-05T11:43:17-07:00",
    "localTimezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "timestamp": "2022-04-05T18:43:17.408Z",
    "id": "<REMOVED>",
    "recipient": {
      "id": "<REMOVED>",
      "name": "Bot",
      "role": "bot"
    },
    "conversation": {
      "id": "<REMOVED>"
    },
    "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:3212"
  },
  "id": "<REMOVED>",
  "timestamp": 1649184197408
}
```